# gl.h: No such file or directory, I can't seem to quell this error

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, qt-creator

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this problem that has been plaguing me.

I am currently using Qt Creator with verion 5.11.3 Qt on Ubuntu to build a project. Every time I try to build I get the error "gl.h: No such file or directory".

The error occurs next to the line in my code that says "#include <gl.h>

I have ran the following code as well and it did not change the outcome

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev
sudo ldconfig
```

I have also tried

```
apt-file update

apt-file search "gl.h"
```

Which then shows this output

```
apt-file search "gl.h"allegro5-doc: /usr/share/doc/allegro5-doc/refman/opengl.html
autoconf-archive: /usr/share/doc/autoconf-archive/html/ax_005fcheck_005fgl.html
autoconf-archive: /usr/share/doc/autoconf-archive/html/ax_005fhave_005fopengl.html
boa-constructor: /usr/share/boa-constructor/Docs/wxpython.ogl.htb
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_TextureUnit__get_combine_alpha_mode_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_TextureUnit__get_combine_arg_operand_alpha_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_TextureUnit__get_combine_arg_operand_rgb_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_TextureUnit__get_combine_arg_src_alpha_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_TextureUnit__get_combine_arg_src_rgb_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_TextureUnit__get_combine_rgb_mode_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_TextureUnit__get_mode_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_TextureUnit__set_combine_alpha_arg_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_TextureUnit__set_combine_arg_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_TextureUnit__set_combine_mode_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_TextureUnit__set_combine_rgb_arg_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_TextureUnit__set_mode_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__compare_function_to_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__compare_mode_to_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__copy_image1d_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__copy_image2d_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__copy_subimage1d_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__copy_subimage2d_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__copy_subimage3d_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__depth_mode_to_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__filter_to_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__get_compare_function_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__get_compare_mode_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__get_depth_mode_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__get_format_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__get_mag_filter_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__get_min_filter_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__get_target_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__get_wrap_mode_r_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__get_wrap_mode_s_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__get_wrap_mode_t_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__set_depth_mode_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__set_image1d_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__set_image2d_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__set_image3d_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__set_mag_filter_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__set_min_filter_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__set_subimage1d_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__set_subimage2d_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__set_subimage3d_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__set_texture_compare_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__set_wrap_mode_gl.html
clanlib-doc: /usr/share/doc/clanlib-doc/Reference/html/CL_Texture__wrap_mode_to_gl.html
compiz-dev: /usr/include/compiz/opengl/opengl.h
emscripten: /usr/share/emscripten/system/include/EGL/egl.h
emscripten: /usr/share/emscripten/system/include/GL/gl.h
emscripten: /usr/share/emscripten/system/include/GLES/gl.h
emscripten: /usr/share/emscripten/system/include/SDL/SDL_opengl.h
emscripten: /usr/share/emscripten/tests/bullet/src/MiniCL/cl_gl.h
erlang-dev: /usr/lib/erlang/lib/wx-1.6.1/include/gl.hrl
erlang-doc: /usr/share/doc/erlang-doc/lib/wx-1.6.1/doc/html/gl.html
erlang-esdl-doc: /usr/share/doc/erlang-esdl-doc/html/gl.html
eso-midas: /usr/lib/eso-midas/15SEP/contrib/tsa/help/scargl.hlc
fltk1.1-doc: /usr/share/doc/fltk1.1-doc/HTML/opengl.html
fltk1.3-doc: /usr/share/doc/fltk1.3-doc/HTML/opengl.html
gfxboot-themes: /etc/bootsplash/themes/KDE/bootloader/gl.hlp
gfxboot-themes: /etc/bootsplash/themes/SLED/bootloader/gl.hlp
gfxboot-themes: /etc/bootsplash/themes/SLES/bootloader/gl.hlp
gfxboot-themes: /etc/bootsplash/themes/openSUSE/bootloader/gl.hlp
gfxboot-themes: /etc/bootsplash/themes/upstream/bootloader/gl.hlp
gfxboot-themes: /usr/share/gfxboot/themes/KDE/help-boot/gl.hlp
gfxboot-themes: /usr/share/gfxboot/themes/SLED/help-boot/gl.hlp
gfxboot-themes: /usr/share/gfxboot/themes/SLES/help-boot/gl.hlp
gfxboot-themes: /usr/share/gfxboot/themes/openSUSE/help-boot/gl.hlp
gfxboot-themes: /usr/share/gfxboot/themes/upstream/help-boot/gl.hlp
gimp-help-ca: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/ca/gimp-config-use-gegl.html
gimp-help-ca: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/ca/gimp-tool-gegl.html
gimp-help-de: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/de/gimp-config-use-gegl.html
gimp-help-de: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/de/gimp-tool-gegl.html
gimp-help-el: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/el/gimp-config-use-gegl.html
gimp-help-el: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/el/gimp-tool-gegl.html
gimp-help-en: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/en/gimp-config-use-gegl.html
gimp-help-en: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/en/gimp-tool-gegl.html
gimp-help-es: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/es/gimp-config-use-gegl.html
gimp-help-es: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/es/gimp-tool-gegl.html
gimp-help-fr: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/fr/gimp-config-use-gegl.html
gimp-help-fr: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/fr/gimp-tool-gegl.html
gimp-help-it: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/it/gimp-config-use-gegl.html
gimp-help-it: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/it/gimp-tool-gegl.html
gimp-help-ja: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/ja/gimp-config-use-gegl.html
gimp-help-ja: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/ja/gimp-tool-gegl.html
gimp-help-ko: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/ko/gimp-config-use-gegl.html
gimp-help-ko: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/ko/gimp-tool-gegl.html
gimp-help-nl: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/nl/gimp-config-use-gegl.html
gimp-help-nl: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/nl/gimp-tool-gegl.html
gimp-help-nn: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/nn/gimp-config-use-gegl.html
gimp-help-nn: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/nn/gimp-tool-gegl.html
gimp-help-pt: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/pt_BR/gimp-config-use-gegl.html
gimp-help-pt: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/pt_BR/gimp-tool-gegl.html
gimp-help-ru: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/ru/gimp-config-use-gegl.html
gimp-help-ru: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/ru/gimp-tool-gegl.html
gimp-help-sl: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/sl/gimp-config-use-gegl.html
gimp-help-sl: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/sl/gimp-tool-gegl.html
gimp-help-sv: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/sv/gimp-config-use-gegl.html
gimp-help-sv: /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/sv/gimp-tool-gegl.html
gnash-doc: /usr/share/doc/gnash-doc/apidoc/html/classgnash_1_1renderer_1_1gles1_1_1bitmap__info__ogl.html
gnash-doc: /usr/share/doc/gnash-doc/apidoc/html/namespacegnash_1_1renderer_1_1opengl.html
gnulib: /usr/share/gnulib/lib/trigl.h
gnuplot-doc: /usr/share/doc/gnuplot-doc/htmldocs/hpgl.html
gnuplot-doc: /usr/share/doc/gnuplot-doc/htmldocs/vgagl.html
golang-1.13-src: /usr/share/go-1.13/misc/cgo/test/testdata/issue27054/egl.h
grass-dev: /usr/lib/grass70/include/grass/dgl.h
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-doc: /usr/share/gtk-doc/html/gst-plugins-bad-libs-1.0/gl.html
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-doc: /usr/share/gtk-doc/html/gst-plugins-bad-libs-1.0/gst-plugins-bad-libs-GstGLContextEagl.html
juce-modules-source: /usr/share/juce/modules/juce_opengl/juce_opengl.h
khronos-api: /usr/include/khronos-api/EGL/egl.h
khronos-api: /usr/include/khronos-api/GL/wgl.h
khronos-api: /usr/include/khronos-api/GLES/gl.h
liballeggl4-dev: /usr/include/alleggl.h
liballegro5-dev: /usr/include/allegro5/allegro_opengl.h
libarb-dev: /usr/include/arb/GL/aw_window_ogl.hxx
libasl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libasl-doc/html/namespaceagl.html
libbogl-dev: /usr/include/bogl/bogl.h
libboinc-app-dev: /usr/include/boinc/api/boinc_gl.h
libboinc-app-dev: /usr/include/boinc/api/x_opengl.h
libboinc-app-dev: /usr/share/boinc-dev/api/boinc_gl.h
libcgal-dev: /usr/include/CGAL/gl.h
libclanlib-dev: /usr/include/ClanLib-1.0/ClanLib/GL/opengl.h
libclanlib-dev: /usr/include/ClanLib-1.0/ClanLib/GL/setupgl.h
libclanlib-dev: /usr/include/ClanLib-1.0/ClanLib/gl.h
libclutter-1.0-dev: /usr/include/clutter-1.0/clutter/egl/clutter-egl.h
libcogl-dev: /usr/include/cogl/cogl/cogl-egl.h
libcogl-dev: /usr/include/cogl/cogl/cogl-texture-2d-gl.h
libcogl-dev: /usr/include/cogl/cogl/cogl.h
libcoin80-dev: /usr/include/Inventor/C/glue/gl.h
libcoin80-dev: /usr/include/Inventor/system/gl.h
libcompute-dev: /usr/include/compute/boost/compute/interop/opengl.hpp
libcompute-dev: /usr/include/compute/boost/compute/interop/opengl/cl_gl.hpp
libcompute-dev: /usr/include/compute/boost/compute/interop/opengl/gl.hpp
libdcmtk-dev: /usr/include/dcmtk/dcmpstat/dvpsgl.h
libdirectfb-dev: /usr/include/directfb/directfbgl.h
libdune-pdelab-dev: /usr/include/dune/pdelab/finiteelementmap/qkdggl.hh
libegl1-mesa-dev: /usr/include/EGL/egl.h
libepoxy-dev: /usr/include/epoxy/egl.h
libepoxy-dev: /usr/include/epoxy/gl.h
libfltk1.1-dev: /usr/include/FL/gl.h
libfltk1.1-dev: /usr/include/FL/gl2opengl.h
libfltk1.3-dev: /usr/include/FL/gl.h
libfltk1.3-dev: /usr/include/FL/gl2opengl.h
libftgl-dev: /usr/include/FTGL/ftgl.h
libgecode-dev: /usr/include/gecode/int/branch/ngl.hpp
libgecode-dev: /usr/include/gecode/set/branch/ngl.hpp
libgegl-dev: /usr/include/gegl-0.3/gegl.h
libgegl-dev: /usr/include/gegl-0.3/npd/npd_gegl.h
libgegl-dev: /usr/include/gegl-0.3/opencl/cl_gl.h
libgegl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libgegl-doc/gegl.h.html
libgeomview-dev: /usr/include/geomview/mgopengl.h
libgfsgl-dev: /usr/include/gerris/gl/gfsgl.h
libgfsgl-dev: /usr/include/gerris/view/gfkgl.h
libghc-fgl-dev: /usr/lib/haskell-packages/ghc/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.3/fgl-5.5.2.3-1PvuJSbzF40BnsvFgNAS4e/Paths_fgl.hi
libghc-fgl-doc: /usr/lib/ghc-doc/haddock/fgl-5.5.2.3/fgl.haddock
libghc-fgl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libghc-fgl-doc/html/src/Paths_fgl.html
libgldi-dev: /usr/include/cairo-dock/gldit/cairo-dock-draw-opengl.h
libgldi-dev: /usr/include/cairo-dock/gldit/cairo-dock-opengl.h
libgles1-mesa-dev: /usr/include/GLES/egl.h
libgles1-mesa-dev: /usr/include/GLES/gl.h
libgrits-dev: /usr/include/grits/grits-opengl.h
libgrits-dev: /usr/include/grits/gtkgl.h
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev: /usr/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gl/egl/gstegl.h
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev: /usr/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gl/egl/gstglcontext_egl.h
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev: /usr/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gl/egl/gstgldisplay_egl.h
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev: /usr/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gl/gl.h
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev: /usr/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gl/glprototypes/opengl.h
libgtkgl2.0-dev: /usr/include/gtkgl-2.0/gtkgl/gdkgl.h
libgtkglext1-dev: /usr/include/gtkglext-1.0/gdk/gdkgl.h
libgtkglext1-dev: /usr/include/gtkglext-1.0/gtk/gtkgl.h
libguichan-dev: /usr/include/guichan/opengl.hpp
libhugs-fgl-bundled: /usr/lib/hugs/packages/fgl/Paths_fgl.hs
libhwloc-dev: /usr/include/hwloc/gl.h
libjuce-dev: /usr/include/juce/modules/juce_opengl/juce_opengl.h
liblablgl-ocaml-dev: /usr/share/doc/liblablgl-ocaml-dev/html/api/Togl.html
liblablgl-ocaml-dev: /usr/share/doc/liblablgl-ocaml-dev/html/api/type_Togl.html
libmgl-dev: /usr/include/mgl2/mgl.h
libmgl-dev: /usr/include/mgl2/opengl.h
libmgl-dev: /usr/include/mgl2/qmathgl.h
libmirclient-dev: /usr/include/mirclient/mir_toolkit/extensions/android_egl.h
libmrpt-dev: /usr/include/mrpt/opengl/include/mrpt/opengl.h
libmyth-dev: /usr/include/mythtv/libmythui/mythpainter_ogl.h
libogre-1.9-dev: /usr/include/OGRE/RenderSystems/GL/GL/gl.h
libpugl-dev: /usr/include/pugl-0/pugl/pugl.h
libqt4-opengl-dev: /usr/include/qt4/Qt/qgl.h
libqt4-opengl-dev: /usr/include/qt4/QtOpenGL/qgl.h
libqt5opengl5-dev: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtOpenGL/qgl.h
libqt5opengl5-gles-dev: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtOpenGL/qgl.h
libqtscript4-doc: /usr/share/doc/libqtscript4-doc/api/com_trolltech_qt_opengl.html
libroot-core5.34: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/root5.34/cint/include/GL/gl.h
libsc-dev: /usr/include/sc/util/render/oogl.h
libsdl1.2-dev: /usr/include/SDL/SDL_opengl.h
libsdl1.2-dev: /usr/share/doc/libsdl1.2-dev/docs/html/guidevideoopengl.html
libsdl2-dev: /usr/include/SDL2/SDL_egl.h
libsdl2-dev: /usr/include/SDL2/SDL_opengl.h
libsofa1-dev: /usr/include/sofa/helper/system/gl.h
libtogl-dev: /usr/include/togl.h
libtogl-dev: /usr/share/doc/libtogl-dev/Togl.html
libva-dev: /usr/include/va/va_backend_egl.h
libva-dev: /usr/include/va/va_egl.h
libvisual-0.4-dev: /usr/include/libvisual-0.4/libvisual/lv_gl.h
libvlccore-dev: /usr/include/vlc/plugins/vlc_opengl.h
libvtk5-dev: /usr/include/vtk-5.10/vtkgl.h
libvtk6-dev: /usr/include/vtk-6.2/vtkgl.h
libvxl1-dev: /usr/include/vxl/contrib/brl/bbas/bocl/bocl_cl_gl.h
libvxl1-dev: /usr/include/vxl/contrib/conversions/geometry/DigitalCurve_to_vdgl.h
libvxl1-dev: /usr/include/vxl/contrib/conversions/geometry/osl_to_vdgl.h
libvxl1-dev: /usr/include/vxl/core/vgui/vgui_gl.h
libwaffle-dev: /usr/include/waffle-1/waffle_x11_egl.h
libwayland-dev: /usr/include/wayland-egl.h
libygl4-dev: /usr/include/X11/Yfgl.h
libygl4-dev: /usr/include/X11/Ygl.h
lush-library: /usr/share/lush/packages/opengl/opengl.hlp
mesa-common-dev: /usr/include/GL/gl.h
mesa-common-dev: /usr/share/doc/mesa-common-dev/egl.html
mingw-w64-common: /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/GL/gl.h
mingw-w64-i686-dev: /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/GL/gl.h
mingw-w64-x86-64-dev: /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/GL/gl.h
mir-doc: /usr/share/doc/mir-doc/html/namespacemir_1_1gl.html
mir-doc: /usr/share/doc/mir-doc/html/namespacemir_1_1renderer_1_1gl.html
mirtest-dev: /usr/include/mirtest/mir/test/doubles/mock_egl.h
mirtest-dev: /usr/include/mirtest/mir/test/doubles/nested_mock_egl.h
mplayer-doc: /usr/share/doc/mplayer-doc/HTML/cs/opengl.html
mplayer-doc: /usr/share/doc/mplayer-doc/HTML/de/opengl.html
mplayer-doc: /usr/share/doc/mplayer-doc/HTML/en/opengl.html
mplayer-doc: /usr/share/doc/mplayer-doc/HTML/fr/opengl.html
mplayer-doc: /usr/share/doc/mplayer-doc/HTML/hu/opengl.html
mplayer-doc: /usr/share/doc/mplayer-doc/HTML/it/opengl.html
mplayer-doc: /usr/share/doc/mplayer-doc/HTML/ru/opengl.html
mplayer-doc: /usr/share/doc/mplayer-doc/HTML/zh_CN/opengl.html
mrpt-doc: /usr/share/doc/mrpt-doc/html/mrpt-opengl.html
mrpt-doc: /usr/share/doc/mrpt-doc/html/namespacemrpt_1_1opengl.html
nvidia-304-dev: /usr/include/nvidia-304/CL/cl_gl.h
nvidia-304-dev: /usr/include/nvidia-304/GL/gl.h
nvidia-304-updates-dev: /usr/include/nvidia-304-updates/CL/cl_gl.h
nvidia-304-updates-dev: /usr/include/nvidia-304-updates/GL/gl.h
nvidia-340-dev: /usr/include/nvidia-340/CL/cl_gl.h
nvidia-340-dev: /usr/include/nvidia-340/GL/gl.h
nvidia-361-dev: /usr/include/nvidia-361/CL/cl_gl.h
nvidia-361-dev: /usr/include/nvidia-361/GL/gl.h
nvidia-384-dev: /usr/include/nvidia-384/CL/cl_gl.h
nvidia-384-dev: /usr/include/nvidia-384/GL/gl.h
opencl-headers: /usr/include/CL/cl_egl.h
opencl-headers: /usr/include/CL/cl_gl.h
paraview-dev: /usr/include/paraview/vtkgl.h
pike7.8-core: /usr/lib/pike7.8/include/opengl.h
pike7.8-reference: /usr/share/doc/pike7.8-doc/html/reference/ex/predef_3A_3A/GTK/GLArea/wait_gl.html
pike8.0-core: /usr/lib/pike8.0/include/opengl.h
pike8.0-doc: /usr/share/doc/pike8.0-doc/html/reference/ex/predef_3A_3A/GTK1/GLArea/wait_gl.html
pyqt5-doc: /usr/share/doc/pyqt5-doc/html/api/qgl.html
pyqt5-doc: /usr/share/doc/pyqt5-doc/html/opengl.html
python-fltk-doc: /usr/share/doc/python-fltk-doc/CH8_Opengl.html
python-pycuda-doc: /usr/share/doc/python-pycuda-doc/html/gl.html
python-pygame: /usr/include/python2.7/pygame/pgopengl.h
python-qt4-doc: /usr/share/doc/python-qt4-doc/html/qgl.html
python-qt4-doc: /usr/share/doc/python-qt4-doc/html/qtopengl.html
python-taurus-doc: /usr/share/doc/python-taurus-doc/html/devel/api/taurus/qt/qtopengl.html
python2.7-doc: /usr/share/doc/python2.7/html/library/gl.html
qpdfview-translations: /usr/share/qpdfview/help_gl.html
qt4-doc-html: /usr/share/qt4/doc/html/activeqt-opengl.html
qt4-doc-html: /usr/share/qt4/doc/html/examples-opengl.html
qt4-doc-html: /usr/share/qt4/doc/html/opengl-hellogl.html
qt4-doc-html: /usr/share/qt4/doc/html/qaxserver-demo-opengl.html
qt4-doc-html: /usr/share/qt4/doc/html/qgl.html
qt4-doc-html: /usr/share/qt4/doc/html/qt-embeddedlinux-opengl.html
qt4-doc-html: /usr/share/qt4/doc/html/qtopengl.html
qt4-doc-html: /usr/share/qt4/doc/html/windowsce-opengl.html
qt4-qmake: /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/ios/GLES/gl.h
qt5-doc-html: /usr/share/qt5/doc/qtdoc/windowsce-opengl.html
qtbase5-dev: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qopengl.h
qtbase5-doc-html: /usr/share/qt5/doc/qtopengl/examples-widgets-opengl.html
qtbase5-doc-html: /usr/share/qt5/doc/qtopengl/qgl.html
qtbase5-gles-dev: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qopengl.h
r-cran-rgl: /usr/lib/R/site-library/rgl/doc/rgl.html
racket-doc: /usr/share/doc/racket/sgl/gl.html
radiance: /usr/lib/radiance/dev/ogl.hdi
texlive-base: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/txt/hyph-gl.hyp.txt
vtk6-doc: /usr/share/doc/vtk6-doc/html/namespacevtkgl.html
wesnoth-1.12-data: /usr/share/doc/wesnoth-1.12-data/manual.gl.html
wx3.0-doc: /usr/share/doc/wx3.0-doc/html/group__group__class__gl.html
```

Comment: "*mesa-common-dev: /usr/include/GL/gl.h*" -- Does this file exist on your machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the OpenGL dev support:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libgl1-mesa-dev
```

You may have a better luck with include of <GL/gl.h>.